# Pandas plot bar charts where X and Y values are column values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset which has 2 columns, column A is binary number 0/1, column B is some characters, 'A','B','C'. Every 'A','B','C' is mapped to a number from column A.

my question is, how do I plot a diagram like the one below ? X values are distinct values from Column B, i.e., 'A', 'B' 'C', for each X value, shows number of 0/1 that is mapped to that X value.

[image]

I also tried :

```
df = df['A'].value_counts().rename("01").to_frame()
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(8, 4),rot=0)
class_names = ['A','B','C']
ax.set_xticklabels(class_names)
```

But it doesn't work..

Comment: Are you open to using `seaborn`?

Comment: @tdy, yes, any method is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Seaborn

One straightforward option is the [**`seaborn.countplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html).

If your data looks something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([0,0,1], size=100), 'B': np.random.choice(['A','A','A','B','C','C'], size=100)})

#     A  B
# 0   0  C
# 1   0  B
# 2   1  B
# .. .. ..
# 97  1  C
# 98  0  A
# 99  0  A
```

Then call [**`seaborn.countplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) with `x='B'` and `hue='A'`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(data=df, x='B', hue='A', order=['A','B','C'])
```

[image: a-b-c countplot]

---

#### Pandas only

To do this with pandas only, you can use [**`DataFrame.GroupBy.size()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```py
df.groupby(['B', 'A']).size().unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image: df groupby bar plot]

---

#### Percentages

Use [**`value_counts(normalize=True)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and add a `%` column:

```py
g = df.groupby(['B'])['A'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().mul(100)
g['%'] = df.B.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)

#           0          1     %
#A  59.574468  40.425532  47.0
#B  66.666667  33.333333  21.0
#C  71.875000  28.125000  32.0
```

Then everything will be structured properly for `plot.bar()`:

```py
g.plot.bar(ylabel='percentage')
```

[image: percentage bar]

Comment: Thaaaankk you ! Just one more question tho, what if I wanted to add a third bar for percentage in addition to 0/1, like the diagram in the question ?

Comment: @zxcisnoias check if the edit at the bottom is what you're looking for

Comment: e.g., blue bar of A means percentage of 0 in A, orange bar of A means percentage of 1 in A, and green bar of A means percentage of A out of A/B/C